# Configure SVN Client in CentOS 7 from CLI

Tags: linux, svn, centos, svn-client

I want to configure a svn client(location, servers, proxy, and authentication) in CentOS from CLI.

I searched but I found info only related to svn server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want know about `~/.subversion`. Check [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.layout):

> The first time the svn command-line client is executed, it creates a
>   per-user configuration area. On Unix-like systems, this area appears
>   as a directory named .subversion in the user's home directory.